# No puedo cargar correctamente un array

Tags: php, array

Estoy queriendo sumar información de la base de datos, pero en algo le estoy errando. Las variables `$ventas` y `$usuarios` están bien, ahora yo quiero recorrer todas las ventas que se realizaron, e ir guardándolas en la variable `arrayProdVendedores`, donde voy a ir armando pares `clave:valor`, donde iría `nombreUsuario:precioVenta`.

Esperaba que la linea `var_dump($arrayProdVendedores);` me devuelva algo como:

```
array(4) { ["Oscar Guerra"]=> string(7) "10841.6", ["Oscar Guerra"]=> string(3) "300", ["Oscar Guerra"]=> string(3) "300",  ["Oscar Guerra"]=> string(6) "205.87"  }
```

Ya que son las 4 ventas que realizó el vendedor. Pero en su lugar, me retorna únicamente la ultima venta, es decir, devuelve:

```
array(1) { ["Oscar Guerra"]=> string(6) "205.87" }
```

Este es el código PHP:

```
<?php
$item = null;
$valor = null;

$ventas = ControladorVentas::ctrMostrarVentas($item,$valor);
$usuarios = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item,$valor);

$arrayVendedores = array();
$arrayProdVendedores = array();

foreach($ventas as $key => $valueVentas){
    foreach ($usuarios as $key => $valueUsuario){
        if($valueUsuario["id"] == $valueVentas["id_vendedor"]){
            # Capturamos vendedores en un array
            array_push($arrayVendedores, $valueUsuario["nombre"]);

            #Caputamos nombres y precios en un mismo array
            $arrayProdVendedores = array($valueUsuario["nombre"] => $valueVentas["precio_productos"]);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($arrayProdVendedores);
?>
```

> Es como si la linea `$arrayProdVendedores = array($valueUsuario["nombre"] => $valueVentas["precio_productos"]);` borraría el contenido del array antes de volver a cargarle datos.... tal vez no es la función correcta la que estoy usando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en está línea:

```
#Caputamos nombres y precios en un mismo array
$arrayProdVendedores = array($valueUsuario["nombre"] => $valueVentas["precio_productos"]);
```

En cada iteración esta pisando el valor de la variable `$arrayProdVendedores` en lugar de agregar valores a la misma.

### Solución:

Para agregar valores a la variable podrías usar [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) o la sintaxis `$array[] = array()` (*que es lo mismo*)

**Ejemplo:**

```
#Caputamos nombres y precios en un mismo array
$arrayProdVendedores[] = array($valueUsuario["nombre"] => $valueVentas["precio_productos"]);
//                  ^ notese los corchetes
```

Comment: Perfecto, me estaba faltando eso, muchas gracias Marcos!